# IBM AppCenter 6.2.0 + SSL on iOS - shows loading view forever when connect to Server (no response fail/success/timeout))

Tags: ios, ssl, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I tried to connect IBM AppCenter 6.2.0.01.20141013-1735 on iOS 6/8.1 (enabled SSL)

After I clicked Login btn, app showed Loading view forever (no fail/success/timeout response).

I checked device log:

> IBMAppCenter[1385:29127] [Appcenter][CordovaPlugin][INFO]: Query login
>   user name:admin server:https://example.net:9443/applicationcenter

Then I disabled network, Application hided loading and showed "no network" message.
I checked log again then saw this:

> 2015-03-31 10:07:13.191 IBMAppCenter[1385:29127]
>   [Appcenter][CordovaPlugin][ERROR]: Query login admin on
>   https://example.net:9443/applicationcenter/FAILED
>   2015-03-31 10:07:13.191 IBMAppCenter[1385:29127] [Appcenter][General][ERROR]:
>   Error handler, http status: null "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."
>   UserInfo=0x7c8c2830
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://example.net:9443/applicationcenter/service/auth,
>   _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://example.net:9443/applicationcenter/service/auth,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline.,
>   _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x7c8c0890 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}"
>   2015-03-31 10:07:13.192 IBMAppCenter[1385:29127] [Appcenter][General][ERROR]: Error handler, displayed message:
>   "Connection failed. Check your connection details (The Internet
>   connection appears to be offline.)."

maybe it was connecting to /service/auth...

I tried on Android, it works fine.
Also tried with no-ssl, it works fine on both Android/iOS.

my SSL was verified by GoDaddy G2.

I am stuck over here and could not find any way out.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the way you have installed the GoDaddy-issued certificate.

First,
Make sure it upholds to the required standards for using a certificate: [IBM AppCenter 6.2.0 + SSL on iOS - shows loading view forever when connect to Server (no response fail/success/timeout))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360020/ibm-appcenter-6-2-0-ssl-on-ios-shows-loading-view-forever-when-connect-to-se)

Second,
Verify you have properly installed it. That is, make sure you did not install it via the Mobile Safari browser, as it won't be available to apps that way (see above link).